# GitLab self-hosted user permission issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have a self-hosted GitLab instance running gitlab-ce:latest docker image and I have trouble granting direct access to repositories for users.

Case:

User `user1` creates a repository under his account called `project` and I'm granting the `Developer` permission to the `project` for `user2`.

When `user2` logged in and try to load Web IDE it's showing the following error message.

[image: GitLab fork prompt]

Is there anyway I can directly grant permission to user without forcing them to create a fork on GitLab CE ?